# Retain old value when refreshing cache?

Tags: java, caffeine-cache

I have a Caffeine AsyncLoadingCache created with a refreshAfterWrite configured. For a given key, if a value is already loaded into the cache and there is an error during refresh, the key/value gets removed.  Instead of this, I would like to retain the old value and update the expiration timestamp so it doesn't immediately get refreshed again.  Is there a way to configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement either [CacheLoader.reload(key, oldValue)](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/b326952a5d29e1a5b2b173bebfb307193ae8bdfa/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.java#L150-L172) or [AsyncCacheLoader.asyncReload(key, oldValue)](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/b326952a5d29e1a5b2b173bebfb307193ae8bdfa/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncCacheLoader.java#L93-L117). When an error occurs it shouldn't remove the old value but can be triggered again on the next call. If the result resolves to `null` then it should be removed. Since the old value is provided, if returned then it would reset the timestamps as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ben!  One thing I neglected to mention is that we are using cache.get(key, mappingFunction) because our loading process needs some data that isn't available during the cache construction.  I don't see a flavor of that which provides access to the oldValue.  Did I miss it?

Comment: @user3380364 Unfortunately it would make the api very messy to provide it explicitly. Instead consider fetching that data on-demand, e.g. through a supplier. In [Guice](https://xvik.github.io/dropwizard-guicey/5.0.0/guide/guice/scopes) or [Spring](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/using-jsr-330-provider.html) this would be a scoped provider, e.g. to query the user's id from a request-scoped supplier. In non-DI code this is often done via a thread-local.

Comment: fwiw, you can also use asMap().compute if you need the old value for an explicit atomic change. That has nothing to do with refreshing though.

Comment: Thanks again Ben for the followup.  One last question - is there any way to get the current value for a key without the cache checking the timestamps and possibly initiating a refresh?

Comment: @user3380364 Take a look at `cache.policy().getIfPresentQuietly(key)`